# How to abstract catching exceptions CompletableFutures for invoking a method

Tags: java, completable-future

Ok, I have methods like

1. CompletableFuture fetchCar(int id);
2. CompletableFuture runSomething(Something t, Extra d);
3. CompletableFuture invoke();

and I would like a single method that I can use that does the following such that it converts any synchronous exceptions to be put in the future

```
private CompletableFuture<Void> invokeSomething(Something something) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future;
    try {
        future = something.runSomething(t, d);
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        future = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
    }

    return future;
}
```

Please note that I just happend to pick #2 as the example but I would like to make that generic so I can stop typing that as in general it needs to be done once in a while to ensure you handle synch and asynch exceptions the same.

Comment: What can `runSomething` throw where it can be handled (a)synchronously? I would expect if that method fails to return normally you'd also want `invokeSomething` to fail (i.e. bubble up the exception) because it'd be something like an NPE or IAE.

Comment: The code above simply puts the synchronous exception in the future so layers above can write one set of code to handle both async and sync exceptions.  So far, there has not been a single reason to ever handle a synchronous exception and asynchronous exception differently.  (and I have been doing futures in scala for 4 years and still have not hit that need.  perhaps it may exist but I 'think' it would be a very very small percentage)

Comment: I think I feel I need to argue with the premise here; generally, a synchronous exception that escapes (isn't reported in a `Future`) is going to be due to programmer error (like an NPE, or index-out-of-bounds), rather than an application error, and you **won't** want them in the same path (in fact, you probably want them to make as much noise as possible).  These errors aren't part of the normal "there was a problem" flow, and shouldn't be reported on the same path.

Comment: Well, maybe take a look at scala finagle filters which EVERY server at twitter uses and does exactly this.  Actually maybe this article will help.. https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2019/gotta-catch--em-all.html

Comment: Ohhh, more importantly, it solved the situation of handling ALL exceptions in one .rescue() function(a function on scala Futures) so you only had to have one block of recovering in any location in twitter code...otherwise you have to handle sync exceptions and async exceptions all over the place and it gets unwieldy really really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you could create a utility function:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> foo(Callable<CompletableFuture<T>> callable) {
    try {
        return callable.call();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(ex);
    }
}
```

You'd then use it like so:

```
Something something = ...;
CompletableFuture<Void> future = foo(() -> invokeSomthing(something));
```

---

Some Notes:

1. Used `Callable` because its functional method, `call`, can throw `Exception`. If something like `Supplier` was used then using it with methods that can throw checked exceptions would be messy.
2. Used `catch (Exception ex)` rather than `catch (Throwable ex)` because `Callable#call` doesn't throw `Throwable` and it's usually considered bad practice to catch `Error`s. You can always change it to `Throwable` if you want.
3. This utility method will return a failed future, caused by an NPE, if the `callable` is `null`; don't know if that's desired.

Comment: I once consulted a team that caught only Exceptions and had spent 1 week trying to figure it out.  I came in and changed 'all' catch statements from Excepiton to Throwable....whallla, problem found...NoClassDefFoundError.  feel free to eventually get burned, but I stick with catch(Throwable e) all day long!!!  It's practical and has never once failed me.  (I don't see why people think it will do something bad...it only helps you).

Comment: oh and damn, I didn't know this failedFuture method existed...holy crap!! that's useful!

Comment: `failedFuture` has been added in Java 9.